# Which font is this? (image attached inside)

Tags: website-design, fonts

Someone please help me in finding the name of the following font:

Note: Only letters, ABHM are displayed.

[image]

Comment: Just tried a google images search, where I uploaded the image. Didn't work. Where did you get this image from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a site callled [identifont.com](http://www.identifont.com/) to figure this out. I tried to but with only four characters it was too difficult to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a better site to identify fonts, you upload the image, enter the letters it's found in the image then it'll come up with a list and show you what it thinks could be your fonts. I also tried those above but didn't seem to find it

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/